# How to update an ActiveRecord_Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to update a database record using `where` method.
This how I proceed:

```
def AjoutAuPanier
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  if @book.nbr_exemplaires > 0
    @p = Panier.where(user_id: current_user, book_id: @book.id)
    if  @p.empty? == false
      @p.update(@p.id, quantity:  @p.quantity + 1)
    else
      @p = Panier.new(user_id: current_user.id , book_id: @book.id , price: @book.price, quantity: 1)
    end
    if @p.save
      @book.update(nbr_exemplaires: @book.nbr_exemplaires-1)
      redirect_to detail_path
    else
      redirect_to books_list_path
    end
  else
    flash[:notice]='Ce livre n\'est plus disponible'
    redirect_to books_list_path
  end
end
```

This, however, gives the following error:

> undefined method `id' for #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@p=Panier.where(user_id: current_user, book_id: @book.id)
```

You must add `.first` because `.where` always return an **array**

```
@p=Panier.where(user_id: current_user, book_id: @book.id).first
```